# Resque::DirtyExit Child process received unhandled signal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, resque

My background jobs are failing randomly with the exception `Resque::DirtyExit Child process received unhandled signal`. After I restart the server they work for some time and then start failing. I suspect something else is going on with my system but not sure where to look. I'm new to Ruby world.

Below is the full output of one of the jobs failing but it's not specific to a particular job. I have number of jobs and they fail or succeed randomly. Also, I'm not running them too frequently. Maybe 1 job every 15 min or so.

```
** [10:26:14 2019-05-02] 47542: Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
** [10:26:14 2019-05-02] 47542: resque-1.27.4: Waiting for critical,high,default,lowest
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: Checking critical
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: Checking high
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: Checking default
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: Found job on default
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: resque-1.27.4: Processing default since 1556807176 [ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper]
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: got: (Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"SomeJob", "job_id"=>"97f5ffc6-61eb-4b9d-9904-4791aaa030a8", "provider_job_id"=>nil, "queue_name"=>"default", "priority"=>nil, "arguments"=>["test"], "executions"=>0, "locale"=>"en"}])
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: Running before_fork hooks with [(Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"SomeJob", "job_id"=>"97f5ffc6-61eb-4b9d-9904-4791aaa030a8", "provider_job_id"=>nil, "queue_name"=>"default", "priority"=>nil, "arguments"=>["test"], "executions"=>0, "locale"=>"en"}])]
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: resque-1.27.4: Forked 48318 at 1556807176
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: resque-retry -- [{"job_class"=>"SomeJob", "job_id"=>"97f5ffc6-61eb-4b9d-9904-4791aaa030a8", "provider_job_id"=>nil, "queue_name"=>"default", "priority"=>nil, "arguments"=>["test"], "executions"=>0, "locale"=>"en"}] [Resque::DirtyExit/Child process received unhandled signal ]: failure backend save
** [10:26:16 2019-05-02] 47541: resque-retry -- [{"job_class"=>"SomeJob", "job_id"=>"97f5ffc6-61eb-4b9d-9904-4791aaa030a8", "provider_job_id"=>nil, "queue_name"=>"default", "priority"=>nil, "arguments"=>["test"], "executions"=>0, "locale"=>"en"}] [Resque::DirtyExit/Child process received unhandled signal ]: non-retryable job is not being retried - sending failure to superclass
```

- My OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4
- Ruby: 2.5.5
- Rails: 5.2.3
- Resque: 1.27.4

Comment: uhmmm probably you run out of memory. How many workers are you running?

Comment: I'm running two workers. How do I check if I'm running out of memory?